# After Windows 7 update and restart, Windows shows black screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have Windows 7 Home Premium. After an update and a restart, I can't get to Windows anymore. My screen is black.

I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> and it takes me to the home screen to change user or task options.  But I can't get anywhwere from there.

Comment: Can you still boot in safe mode? Hold F8 during windows boot and select safe mode.

Comment: Leave it and wait... I've seen the `Black Screen after Reboot` problem several times... Once it even took 45 mins to 'clear'.

Comment: Did you notice if the windows updates included Service Pack1?  And does the black screen have anything written on it, like maybe "c0000034"?

Comment: Are you able to start Task Manager from the `Ctrl+Alt+Del` screen? You can execute programs from the Task Manager, and you can try to kill a hung process. I'd recommend killing and restarting `explorer.exe`.

Comment: +1 for "leave it and wait". On my laptop, coming out of sleep also does the same thing, and I have to leave it for over a minute to wake up fully.